# GitFlow: safely merge develop changes to a feature branch

Tags: git, git-flow

Recently I started working on a big features, so I created a new `feature/xyz` branch. Problem is that this feature is big, so it will take me ~3 months to complete it. I would like to safely merge progress that has been made in `develop` to my feature branch, without worrying that changes from `develop` branch will override updates that I already made in my feature branch. My previous attempt to merge `develop` to `feature/xyz` ended up in some changes that I already made in the new feature being reverted.

What would be the command to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: `My previous attempt to merge develop to feature/xyz ended up in some changes that I already made in the new feature being reverted.` - this is not normally what should have happened - your workflow should work. Were there merge conflicts? Are you make large refactoring changes?

Comment: No merge conflicts. If file was changed both in ``develop`` and ``feature/xyz`` branch, Git favoured versions from ``develop``. I really can't recollect how it exactly happened because I discovered problems later on.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### **The only safety is in learned, discerning and frequent merges.**

Only you understand how the code on `develop` and `feature/xyz` aligns, no one else. It is only you who can merge the two flows correctly in a discerning way. Even with the default merging strategies, which are far less dangerous than `-S ours` or `-X theirs` you still always have to review the result.

You may need some help of course, and git will offer some. For example, you can use git recorded resolutions - [rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) to help with making the same correct merge decision after you made one initially.

A fairly common, and relatively simple model, using the names you’ve supplied for the branches, could work for you like this,

- `develop` is the branch where the main thrust of development occurs
- `xyz` is the branch where you develop the feature xyz
- `xyz_stage` is the branch where you merge the `develop` and the `xyz` code, keeping that branch stable in line with the respective stable points of `develop` and `xyz`. This is also the branch that you’d eventually merge back into develop when you are ready to release feature xyz or part of thereof.

The above assumes that not only you merge `xyz` into `xyz_stage` but that you also merge `develop` into `xyz_stage` from time to time and make sure that the portions of `xyz` so far released to `xyz_stage` work and pass the relevant tests in conjunction with the code from `develop`.

Nevertheless, you still have to choose how do you make the `xyz` branch, where you work on the feature, aware of the progress on develop.

The cleanest option is - don’t make it aware. That’s why you have `xyz_stage` where the two development flows come together. This approach is feasible and sane as long as the development of `xyz` is not prolonged.

The second option is to merge `xyz_stage` back into `xyz` when you are happy with the staging branch. That way you will have stable point that you can continue and develop the `xyz` feature on top.

Here's a simple illustration of the process, with comments:

[image: Feature xyz]

Comment: Creation of stage branch works well. First, we branch develop into stage branch, than merge feature into stage, resolve any conflict and than merge it back into feature.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the only "safe" solution is to always manually inspect and test the result of any merge. --no-commit will stage the merge and let you inspect it before committing, or you can reset/amend, whatever feels more practical. Getting a three-way-merge tool can be very helpful. There are just too many ways things can break without there being merge conflicts, that relying on automatic merging is bound to get you into trouble. If you have 100% test coverage, sure, you can be a bit more relaxed, but how many projects can really claim that? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git merge -s recursive -X ours`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies). This will cause conflicts in the two branches to always resolve using the version in the checked out directory (`feature/xyz` in this case).

**Important**: contrary to your title, **this strategy is not necessarily "safe"**: the modifications from `develop` might conflict the the ones in `feature/xyz`. As always, make sure to properly test the merged changes.